# R minimize absolute error

Tags: r

Here's my setup

```
obs1<-c(1,1,1)
obs2<-c(0,1,2)
obs3<-c(0,0,3)

absoluteError<-function(obs,x){
  return(sum(abs(obs-x)))
}

Example:
> absoluteError(obs2,1)
[1] 2
```

For a random vector of observations, I'd like to find a minimizer, `x`,  which minimizes the absolute error between the observation values and a vector of all `x`.  For instance, clearly the argument that minimizes `absoluteError(obs1,x)` is x=1 because this results in an error of 0.  How do I find a minimizer for a random vector of observations?  I'd imagine this is a linear programming problem, but I've never implemented one in R before.

Comment: Upon further thought, the median is a minimizer.  Not sure how to proceed - should I delete my question?

Comment: No.  Please do not.  Rather, post your comment as an answer, perhaps with R code that supports your conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The median of obs is a minimizer for the absolute error.  The following is a sketch of how one might try proving this:

Let the median of a set of n observations, obs, be m.  Call the absolute error between obs and m f(obs,m).

Case n is odd: 
Consider f(obs,m+delta) where delta is some non zero number.  Suppose delta is positive - then there are (n-1)/2 +1 observations whose error is delta more than f(obs,m).  The remaining (n-1)/2 observations' error is at most delta less than f(obs,m).  So f(obs,m+delta)-f(obs,m)>=delta.  (The same argument can be made if delta is negative.) So the median is the only minimizer in this case. Thus f(obs,m+delta)>f(obs,m) for any non zero delta so m is a minimizer for f.

Case n is even: 
Basically the same logic as above, except in this case any number between the two inner most numbers in the set will be a minimizer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this answer is correct, and even if it is I am not sure this is what you want.  Nevertheless, I am taking a stab at it.

I think you are talking about 'Least absolute deviations', a form of regression that differs from 'Least Squares'.

If so, I found this R code for solving Least absolute deviations regression:

```
fabs=function(beta0,x,y){
  b0=beta0[1]
  b1=beta0[2]
  n=length(x)
  llh=0
     for(i in 1:n){
          r2=(y[i]-b0-b1*x[i])
          llh=llh + abs(r2)
     }
  llh
}

g=optim(c(1,1),fabs,x=x,y=y)
```

I found the code here:

http://www.stat.colostate.edu/~meyer/hw12ans.pdf

Assuming you are talking about Least absolute deviations, you might not be interested in the above code if you want a solution in `R` from scratch rather than a solution that uses `optim`.

The above code is for a regression line with an intercept and one slope.  I modified the code as follows to handle a regression with just an intercept:

```
y <- c(1,1,1)
x <- 1:length(y)

fabs=function(beta0,x,y){
  b0=beta0[1]
  b1=0
  n=length(x)
  llh=0
    for(i in 1:n){
       r2=(y[i]-b0-b1*x[i])
       llh=llh + abs(r2)
    }
  llh
}

# The commands to get the estimator

g = optim(c(1),fabs,x=x,y=y, method='Brent', lower = (min(y)-5), upper = (max(y)+5))
g
```

I was not familiar with (i.e., had not heard of) Least absolute deviations until tonight.  So, hopefully my modifications are fairly reasonable.

With `y <- c(1,1,1)` the parameter estimate is `1` (which I think you said is the correct answer):

```
$par
[1] 1

$value
[1] 1.332268e-15

$counts
function gradient 
      NA       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

With `y <- c(0,1,2)` the parameter estimate is `1`:

```
$par
[1] 1

$value
[1] 2

$counts
function gradient 
      NA       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

With `y <- c(0,0,3)` the parameter estimate is `0` (which you said is the correct answer):

```
$par
[1] 8.613159e-10

$value
[1] 3

$counts
function gradient 
      NA       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

If you want `R` code from scratch, there is additional `R` code in the file at the link above which might be helpful.

Alternatively, perhaps it might be possible to extract the relevant code from the source file.

Alternatively, perhaps someone else can provide the desired code (and correct any errors on my part) in the next 24 hours.

If you come up with code from scratch please post it as an answer as I would love to see it myself.

Comment: can you please take a look at this? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95244/using-nelder-mead-algorithm-for-minimizing-the-sum-of-absolute-deviations-from-t

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
 lad=function(x,y){
  SAD = function(beta, x, y) {
    return(sum(abs(y - (beta[1] + beta[2] * x))))
  }
  d=lm(y~x)
  ans1 = optim(par=c(d$coefficients[1], d$coefficients[2]),method = "Nelder-Mead",fn=SAD, x=x, y=y)
  coe=setNames(ans1$par,c("(Intercept)",substitute(x)))
  fitted=setNames(ans1$par[1]+ans1$par[2]*x,c(1:length(x)))
  res=setNames(y-fitted,c(1:length(x)))
  results = list(coefficients=coe, fitted.values=fitted, residuals=res)
  class(results)="lad"
  return(results)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).